# How do I set a custom 404 for a php herokuapp?

Tags: php, html, heroku, http-status-code-404

I see all these threads for setting custom 404s and other error codes for a RoR herokuapp, but I see nothing for plain HTML apps (in this case, just using a one-line index.php to serve the home.html file) How would I get herokuapp to stop showing the default "This file isn't on the server" to my own? I tried changing the error page in the settings, then realized that's for when the app doesn't even load, so that won't work. (Basically I want [this](http://rooday.herokuapp.com/404.html) to show instead of [this](http://rooday.herokuapp.com/asdsa)) Any suggestions?

Comment: why the downvotes? Searching google and stackoverflow all show answers that work for rails only, unless "how to set a 404 page in a herokuapp" is the wrong search criteria...

Comment: Because it has nothing to do with Heroku or PHP.

Comment: Also, use an empty `composer.json` file, then you can save yourself the `index.php` workaround and rename your `home.html` to `index.html` instead: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#activation

Comment: Thanks, just did that, this will save me some time in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really is an Apache-specific question. Create a `.htaccess` with `ErrorDocument 404 404.html`. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware heroku used .htaccess files.